# Organizar lista baseado em um valor inteiro dos elementos dela

Tags: java, android, classificação

Tenho um `ArrayList` de uma classe minha que contém variáveis `String` e inteiros, como um nome e pontuação. Quando a exibo através de um `Adapter` gostaria que a lista estivesse com a pontuação em ordem decrescente, mas não encontrei como faço isso. Alguém sabe como? No caso o texto é o nome a pontuação é a aprovação do comentário.

Abaixo segue a parte em que crio a lista e a exibo:

```
public class F_ListaComentarios extends ListFragment {

    C_Comentario comentario;
    private List<C_Comentario> comentarios;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        comentarios = new ArrayList<C_Comentario>();

        preencherListaComentarios(comentarios);

        if (comentarios != null) {
            adapter = new P_ComentarioAdapter(getActivity(), comentarios);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.f_lista_comentarios, null, false);
        return (view);
    }

    public void preencherListaComentarios(ArrayList<C_Comentario> comentarios) {

        C_Comentario comentario = new C_Comentario();
        comentario.setTexto("AA");
        comentario.setAprovado(0);
        comentarios.add(comentario);

        C_Comentario comentario2 = new C_Comentario();
        comentario.setTexto("AV");
        comentario.setAprovado(2);
        comentarios.add(comentario);

        C_Comentario comentario3 = new C_Comentario();
        comentario.setTexto("AA");
        comentario.setAprovado(1);
        comentarios.add(comentario);

        C_Comentario comentario4 = new C_Comentario();
        comentario.setTexto("AA");
        comentario.setAprovado(5);
        comentarios.add(comentario);
    }
}
```

Consegui resolver implementando `Comparable<C_Comentario>` à minha classe `C_Comentario` e adicionando

```
public static final Comparator<C_Comentario> DESCENDING_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<C_Comentario>() {
        // Overriding the compare method to sort the age
        public int compare(C_Comentario c, C_Comentario c1) {
            return c1.aprovado - c.aprovado;
        }
    };

e

@Override
    public int compareTo(C_Comentario c) {
        return (this.titulo).compareTo(c.titulo);
    }
}
```

a classe também.

No `fragment` só precisei chamar

```
Collections.sort(comentarios, C_Comentario.DESCENDING_COMPARATOR);
```

Comment: Coloca o código de como estás a fazer para vermos e poder ajudar melhor

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o método [`Collections.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) passando como argumento o seu `ArrayList` e um objeto `Comparator<T>`. A própria `Collections` fornece o `Collections.reverseOrder`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

// ...
ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();
lista.add(432);
lista.add(23);
lista.add(18);
lista.add(2);
lista.add(100);

Collections.sort(lista, Collections.reverseOrder());
System.out.println(lista); // [432, 100, 23, 18, 2]
```

---

<kbd>[Exemplo funcionando no Ideone](http://ideone.com/tfIR3O)</kbd>